# How do I submit form via: PHP sending email, Using Ajax for no screen refresh, and post a message next to form with no screen refresh?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms

When the user clicks on the submit button I need:
(1) The form data to be sent to me via email using PHP, without refreshing the page.
(2) A thank you message to appear next to the form using Ajax.

I've got most of it working. I'm not to sure what coding I need to make the page NOT refresh as the PHP script is sending the form data to me via email. Also, once the PHP script is done running, how do I get the Ajax code to run? I've done a ton of research and have found a lot of people use jQuery to resolve this issue.  However, I am not using jQuery for this just JavaScript.  I know I am close, but need some help.  Here is my code thus far:

PHP - Just sends the form data to me via email:

```
<?php
$persons_name = $_POST['fname'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$comments_questions = $_POST['moreinfo'];

$to = 'fireplace_tea@yahoo.com';
$subject = 'Email - JulesMyers.com';
$msg = "$persons_name has sent an email.\n" .
"You can reply to $persons_name at: $email_address\n" .
"Question or Comment: $comments_questions\n";
mail($to, $subject, $msg, 'From: ' . $email_address);
?>
```

HTML Form:

```
<form id="contactMe" method="post" action="contact.php">
 <input type="text" class="inputElement initialColor" name="fname" id="fname">
 <input type="text" class="inputElement initialColor" name="email" id="email">
 <textarea rows="6" class="inputElement" name="moreinfo" id="moreinfo"> </textarea>
 <input type="submit" class="sendButton" id="submitbutton" value="Send">
</form> 
<div class="errormsg"></div>
<div class="formsent"></div>
```

Ajax: I have the Ajax working when I click the formsent div, but I need it to run after the PHP script does. Is there an event I can listen for?

```
(function() {
  var httpRequest;
  var b = document.querySelector('.formsent');
  b.onclick = function() { makeRequest('thanks.txt'); };

  function makeRequest(url) 
  {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, ...
      httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
      try {
        httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
      } 
      catch (e) {
        try {
          httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } 
        catch (e) {}
      }
    }

    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = alertContents;
    httpRequest.open('POST', url);
    httpRequest.send();
  }

  function alertContents() {
    if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) 
    {
      if (httpRequest.status === 200) 
      {
        /*alert(httpRequest.responseText);*/
        b.innerHTML = httpRequest.responseText;
      } 
    }
  }
})();
```

Thanks for any help.  :)

Comment: before httpRequest.send() declare FormData, put your contact form into FormData, google it lots of example.

Comment: Thanks wayne, I am looking into this.  FormData is relatively new, so is there a more backwards compatible way of doing this as well?

Comment: iframe trick. Google post form via iframe. but kind of bad trick

Comment: Why don't you just use JQuery? It would be so much simpler for you to achieve what you're trying to do.

Comment: @TheTaxPayer:  I will probably end up using the jQuery way on my website.  But, I'm trying to see how it's done and jQuery kind of hides that.  I have learned a number of things so far.

Answer (score 1):

WooHoo!  I figured it out without using jQuery...in other words I did it the long way.  I did a ton of research and trying things out.  How it works is when the user clicks on the button labeled submit JavaScript\DOM gets and stores the values from the three form fields, than XMLhttpRequest\AJAX gets the values that JavaScript\DOM stored and sends them to the PHP file, than the PHP file sends me an email with the form data, and finally httpRequest.responseText puts a thank you message next to the form for the user to see.  All of this gets done withOUT the page refreshing.  Yeah! Here is the coding that works:

HTML

```
<form id="contactMe">
 <input type="text" class="inputElement initialColor" name="fname" id="fname">
 <input type="text" class="inputElement initialColor" name="email" id="email">
 <textarea rows="6" class="inputElement" name="moreinfo" id="moreinfo"> </textarea>
 <input type="button" class="sendButton" id="submitbutton" value="Send">
</form> 
<div class="errormsg"></div>
<div class="formsent"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
function makeRequest()
{
    var httpRequest;
    var personName = document.getElementById('fname').value;
    var emailAddress = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var comments = document.getElementById('moreinfo').value;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { 
      httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { 
      try {
        httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
      } 
      catch (e) {
        try {
          httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } 
        catch (e) {}
      }
    }

    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = alertContents;
    httpRequest.open("GET", "contact.php?name="+personName+"&email="+emailAddress+"&comment="+comments, true);
    httpRequest.send();

    function alertContents() 
      {
        if (httpRequest.readyState === 4 && httpRequest.status === 200) 
        {
            var thankYou = document.querySelector('.formsent');
            thankYou.innerHTML = httpRequest.responseText;

            var clearForm = document.getElementById('contactMe');
            clearForm.reset();
        }
      }
}
```

PHP

```
<?php
$name = $_GET['name'];
$email = $_GET['email'];
$comment = $_GET['comment'];

$to = 'email@fakeDomain.fake';
$subject = 'Email From Website Form';
$msg = "$name has sent an email.\n" .
"You can reply to $name at: $email\n" .
"Question or Comment: $comment\n";
mail($to, $subject, $msg, 'From: ' . $email); 

echo "Thank you " . $name . ".<br>";
echo "The form has been sent.";
?>
```

The hardest part was figuring out how to pass variables from JavaScript to PHP.  It took time to find really good full examples, and to also find explanations of how it works.  Here are a couple of resources I found very helpful: 
tutorials2learn.com/tutorials/scripts/ajax-scripts/submit-html-form-ajax.html 
javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/ajaxgetpost.shtml 
javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/ajaxgetpost2.shtml 
openjs.com/articles/ajax_xmlhttp_using_post.php 
webcheatsheet.com/php/passing_javascript_variables_php.php 
stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/reference-why-does-the-php-or-other-server-side-code-in-my-javascript-not-wor

A few notes: 
* I used AJAX (XMLHttpRequest object) to open a communication line between JavaScript and PHP. 
* This entire operation can be done in jQuery with less lines of coding. But, I wanted to know how it worked the long way.  So, now when I look at the jQuery coding I understand what it is doing.

Comment: You could have instead asked for the logic; it's simple. When you submit the form, you validate it with JS function and on success, you call `AJAX` and at the `end` of this function, you return false. In success function of AJAX, you alert the thank you message. In backend, you retrieve the data sent by AJAX and use mail function to send the mail. Once mail is sent, you `echo` a `flag` status which you verify in success function of AJAX. So, this communication do not lets page to reload and send mail as well!

Comment: @marcus - I do have form validation done first, than once validation passes it calls the Ajax function.  Also, I noticed that return false didn't always work (e.preventDefault does)...and I didn't need to stop default behavior anyway since I used type="button", NOT type="submit".

Comment: @marcus - I don't know PHP that well.  Why did you suggest echo a flag?  What does flag do?

Comment: flag is any identifier you use to identify the result. Suppose, you use `echo "success";` or `echo true;` in php file, then "success" and "true" are called as flags as you can now use their values in JS to check against if the script has run properly or not. And yeah, as you have used type=button, no need of return false. However, e.preventDefault will prevent future click of events (I guess) and so return false is the better approach as it does perform the task needed.